# Find working directory from Ant

Tags: java, ant

Is it possible to tell which directory the user ran Ant from?

For example, I might want to run only the unit tests in the current working directory, rather than all tests for the entire project.

I tried this:

```
<property environment="env" />
<echo>${env.CWD}</echo>
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: CWD is not part of a typical Windows set of environment variables.  How are you setting it?  The answer @Asaph provided is way more strightforward.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The whole Properties object returned by `System.getProperties()` is exposed by Ant. Try this:

```
<echo>${user.dir}</echo>
```

Answer (score 45):

`${basedir}` might also be useful.

In Netbeans under Linux, `${user.dir}` seems always to equal `${user.home}`, but `${basedir}` gives me actual directory where ant is ran from (so it gives me the project dir).

Comment: By default, basedir is the parent directory of the buildfile. This is not necessarily the same as the *working directory.*

Comment: That actually is exactly my problem. I can't figure out how to get my working directory to be some other directory when I invoke my ant script from a different ant script in another directory. I see user.dir is the directory of the calling ant script, and basedir is the directory that I want to execute my ant script from. I call my ant script using `<ant target="default" inheritAll="true" dir="${otherDirectory}"/>`, but that only changes the basedir and not the current working directory.

Comment: ${basedir} resolves to the directory containing the build file when/if you execute Ant with the *-f somebuildfileinsomeotherpath* flag. So that's not a good flag to use to get the current directory from where you are invoking ant.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using Windows, this will give you the current working directory:

```
<exec executable="sh" outputproperty="my.cwd"><arg line="-c pwd"/></exec>
```

Comment: The command works, but it is against the Ant spirit "write once, build everywhere" as it does not run under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

and under windows

```
<exec executable="cmd" outputproperty="my.cwd"><arg line="/C echo %cd%"/></exec>
```

see also [Using ant to detect os and set property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453170/using-ant-to-detect-os-and-set-property)