# Passing an entire file to JVM arguments

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have several systems that all need to load the same properties to the JVM.  I can use the -D flag to load one property at a time, but i am looking for something that will load all the properties in an entire file at one time.  For instance:

I could just add --options-file=blah.properties to all jvms on my network, once, and from then on only change the properties file, which could be a single central file over a network share.

Thank you,

EDIT: Any arguments or commands must also work in a windows environment.  Therefore any bash or scripting hacks specific to unix will not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's roughly how we do it:

`java $(tr '\n' ' ' < options_file) other args...`

Here `options_file` contains ready `-Dsomething` or `-Xsomething` values, one per line. The `tr` command just replaces every newline with a space.

Comment: @doug: it will not. Under windows, you need something like `for /S delim=...`, can't remember, but windows does provide a way to read a file line by line; you add these lines to an environment variable.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can do that via the command line (without some bash hacks, perhaps), but you definitely can do that programatically:

Simply set one property `-DmyPropertiesFile=/your/properties/file.properties` and then read that with one of the `Properties.load()` overloads. After that, `System.setProperties(yourProps)` should do what you expect.

Of course, this requires that you can hook this code early enough so that your properties will be available when needed (For instance, if the `main()` method is yours, this is perfect).

Comment: I don't think this will work because both the web application and the log4j application need access to the same variables...

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

1. Wrap your properties in your .jar file and then get your processes to read that properties file from `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`
2. Write a batch file to execute your Java processes, and either explicitly list the -D options, or create the command line dynamically.

I solve this problem normally by using Spring (used for other reasons too) and a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html). That allows me to specify one or more locations for property files and modifies the Spring configuration in-place.

Comment: getClass().getResourceAsStream() is something you do inside the app after it's started, right?
I need this to happen before any application gets started..

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ant to lanuch the Java process, 9000's answer (plus his windows comment) will work, and you can have the launcher deal with the OS difference.

There is a StackOverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453170/using-ant-to-detect-os-and-set-property) which describes how to determine the OS from ant