# ANT root directory

Tags: ant

**How to get the ant root directory (in a crossplatform way) ?**

For example:

- in linux or macosx would be: `/`
- in windows would be: `C:/`
- etc..

*Thanks..*

Comment: what do you mean ant root dir would be c:/ in windows and / in linux?

Comment: yes. I would like to get a property with for example C:/ in windows and / in linux

Comment: you can try this option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453170/using-ant-to-detect-os-and-set-property/32711314#32711314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get that directly.

Probably, you can get the `user.home` system property and extract the root from it.