# How To Run Pylint From Ant

Tags: python, ant, jenkins, continuous-integration, pylint

I need to run this command from ant:

```
pylint -f parseable src/apps/api | tee pylint.out
```

It outputs a pylint.out file.

I tried this:

```
<target name="pylint" description="Pylint">
    <exec executable="pylint">
        <arg line="-f parseable src/apps/api | tee ${basedir}/pylint.out"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

But that doesn't produce the pylint.out file. Any ideas?

Comment: you need both output in a file and on stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that ant will treat your pipe (`|`) as an argument rather than a command to the shell.

One solution would be to extract your command to a script:

**pylint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
pylint -f parseable src/apps/api | tee $1/pylint.out
```

and then run that script from the `<exec>` task:

**build.xml:**

```
<target name="pylint" description="Pylint">
    <exec executable="pylint.sh">
        <arg line="${basedir}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

That's obviously not cross-platform and there may be a better way that I haven't thought of, but you could have an equivalent `.bat` file and do [OS-detection in ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453170/using-ant-to-detect-os-and-set-property) to make it work on Windows if needed.